# Azure container fails to configure and then 'terminated'

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

I have a Docker container with an ASP.NET (.NET 4.7) web application. The Docker image works perfectly using our local docker deployment, but will not start on Azure and I cannot find any information or diagnostics on why that might be.

From the log stream I get

```
31/05/2019 11:05:34.487 INFO - Site: ip-app-develop-1 - Creating container for image: 3tcsoftwaredockerdevelop.azurecr.io/irs-plus-app:latest-develop.
31/05/2019 11:05:34.516 INFO - Site: ip-app-develop-1 - Create container for image: 3tcsoftwaredockerdevelop.azurecr.io/irs-plus-app:latest-develop succeeded. Container Id 1ea16ee9f5f128f14246fefcd936705bb8a655dc6cdbce184fb11970ef7b1cc9
31/05/2019 11:05:40.151 INFO - Site: ip-app-develop-1 - Start container succeeded. Container: 1ea16ee9f5f128f14246fefcd936705bb8a655dc6cdbce184fb11970ef7b1cc9
31/05/2019 11:05:43.745 INFO - Site: ip-app-develop-1 - Application Logging (Filesystem): On
31/05/2019 11:05:44.919 INFO - Site: ip-app-develop-1 - Container ready
31/05/2019 11:05:44.919 INFO - Site: ip-app-develop-1 - Configuring container
31/05/2019 11:05:57.448 ERROR - Site: ip-app-develop-1 - Error configuring container
31/05/2019 11:06:02.455 INFO - Site: ip-app-develop-1 - Container has exited
31/05/2019 11:06:02.456 ERROR - Site: ip-app-develop-1 - Container customization failed
31/05/2019 11:06:02.470 INFO - Site: ip-app-develop-1 - Purging pending logs after stopping container
31/05/2019 11:06:02.456 INFO - Site: ip-app-develop-1 - Attempting to stop container: 1ea16ee9f5f128f14246fefcd936705bb8a655dc6cdbce184fb11970ef7b1cc9
31/05/2019 11:06:02.470 INFO - Site: ip-app-develop-1 - Container stopped successfully. Container Id: 1ea16ee9f5f128f14246fefcd936705bb8a655dc6cdbce184fb11970ef7b1cc9
31/05/2019 11:06:02.484 INFO - Site: ip-app-develop-1 - Purging after container failed to start
```

After several restart attempts (manual or as a result of re-configuration) I will simply get:

```
2019-05-31T10:33:46  The application was terminated.
```

The application then refuses to even attempt to start regardless of whether I use the az cli or the portal.

My current logging configuration is:

```
{
  "applicationLogs": {
    "azureBlobStorage": {
      "level": "Off",
      "retentionInDays": null,
      "sasUrl": null
    },
    "azureTableStorage": {
      "level": "Off",
      "sasUrl": null
    },
    "fileSystem": {
      "level": "Verbose"
    }
  },
  "detailedErrorMessages": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "failedRequestsTracing": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "httpLogs": {
    "azureBlobStorage": {
      "enabled": false,
      "retentionInDays": 2,
      "sasUrl": null
    },
    "fileSystem": {
      "enabled": true,
      "retentionInDays": 2,
      "retentionInMb": 35
    }
  },
  "id": "/subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/XXX/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/XXX/config/logs",
  "kind": null,
  "location": "North Europe",
  "name": "logs",
  "resourceGroup": "XXX",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config"
}
```

Further info on the app:
 - deployed using a docker container
 - docker base image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.7.2
 - image entrypoint c:\ServiceMonitor.exe w3svc
 - app developed in ASP.NET 4.7
 - using IIS as a web server

**Questions:**

How can I get some diagnostics on what is going on to enable me to determine why the app is not starting?

Why does the app refuse to even attempt to restart after a few failed attempts?

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: No I didn't. I only seem to get it with windows container, not our ubuntu ones. We ended up creating a server core VM (in Azure) and installing docker on it and running the container in there (where the same container ran fine). I think it may be something to do with Azure Web Containers falsely detecting that the site hasn't started up, maybe because IIS is slow to start. Also, on container startup we do some configuration that causes the app pool to recycle, which may have caused Web Containers to think the container had failed to start correctly

Answer (score 1):

We have had the same issue, at last we have seen that Appservice is mounting a directory with a "special cooked" version of servicemonitor.exe this version reads the events from the backend of the appservice. If you change your docker image for use this version of service monitor will work. We have created a small powershell and changed the entrypoint from this:

```
#WORKDIR /LogMonitor
SHELL ["C:\\LogMonitor\\LogMonitor.exe", "powershell.exe"]
# Start IIS Remote Management and monitor IIS 
ENTRYPOINT Start-Service WMSVC; C:/ServiceMonitor.exe w3svc;
```

to this:

```
   ENTRYPOINT ["C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe","-File","C:\\start-iis-environment.ps1"]
```

and we have created this powershell like:

```
if (Test-Path -Path 'C:\AppService\Util\ServiceMonitor.exe' -PathType Leaf) {
   & C:\AppService\Util\ServiceMonitor.exe w3svc
}
else{
   & C:\ServiceMonitor.exe w3svc
}
```

Comment: I think this is similar (if not the same) as the original issue that I had. It seemed that, for whatever reason, that docker was falsely detecting the service had failed or not started. We think it might have been due to the long IIS start-up time.